# Какие есть методы сборки кода на игровых движках? Какой лучше для примитивного 2d вроде vn генератора?

Tags: c, разработка-игр

Задача была сделать маленькую новеллу. Новеллу сделал на [Nuclear](https://github.com/Immediate-Mode-UI/Nuklear) + SDL2 + Toml. Никокого 3D там не придвидется, и рендер идёт через SDL. Для вывода спрайтов и текста - выше крыши. И вот немного посидев подумал, почему бы не доделать из этого свой велосипед - аля генератор визуальных новелл, на минималках.

Игры я никода не делал и движки тоже. Столкнулся с тем, что если делать прям движок, то нужен либо код генератор, либо скриптовой язык типа **Lua**. Решил попробовать пойти по сложному пути и попробовать генерировать компилируемый код, а не скриптовой, соответственно в итоге просто компилировать всю игровую логику. Из переносимых компиляторов **C** нашел только [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/). Так что-бы разорхивировать и работать, без подтягивания пакетов из интернета, и большой инфраструктуры и т.д.

Соответственно вопрос есть какой-то способ кроссплатформенной генерации **C** кода из предустановленных файлов, как к примеру компилятор **NASM** - разорхивировал и работай. В принципе уже начал посматривать на **Golang** или **Zig**, т.к. там надо будет при установке движка просто идин раз распаковать архив.

Ну и вопрос к людям которые вообще игры делают, может я из-за неопытности занимаюсь хернёй и надо делать всё совсем подругому?

Comment: Gcc jit, llvm jit

Comment: Проще использовать существующие развитые инструменты, типа Visual Studio.